# Regex in a iterative manner only for Json Keys

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to replace the dots with a different symbol using regex. But unable to add all the dots in capturing groups to replace. Basically this dots needs to be replaced only for keys.
I have tried with `[\w\d]*([.])]*` which gets me all the instances where dots exists with words. But unable to set it just for keys.
If at all try ending the expression with `"` and `:` like `[\w\d]+?([.])]*?[\w\d]+?[":]` it selects only the last part of the key or value.

```
{
  "header": {
    "dataModelVersion": "3"
  },
  "content": {
          "sasl.kerberos.service.name": {
            "displayName": "Kerberos Service Name",
            "identifiesControllerService": false,
            "name": "sasl.kerberos.service.name",
            "sensitive": false
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your input json, here I have assume that there is no digit present on json key. So, there is no need to add `\d` on regex.

Here, I have replace `dot (.)` on json key with character `underscore (_)`. Yes, you can replace with any character if you want.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([\\w\\.]*)\"[:]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    .matcher(json);
while(matcher.find()) {
    if(matcher.group().contains(".")) {
        json = json.substring(0, matcher.start()) 
            + matcher.group().replace(".", "_") 
                + json.substring(matcher.end());
    }
}
System.out.println(json);
```

Result of this program as below:

```
{
  "header": {
    "dataModelVersion": "3"
  },
  "content": {
    "sasl_kerberos_service_name": {
      "displayName": "Kerberos Service Name",
      "identifiesControllerService": false,
      "name": "sasl.kerberos.service.name",
      "sensitive": false
    }
  }
}
```